# Importing custom functions in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am trying to reuse some common custom functions for data science projects. I am saving the functions as a .py file and calling them in a jupyter notebook.
These functions use some modules such as seaborn, matplotlib which I already import in the jupyter notebook. When I call the function, it however throws up an error of not finding these modules. This may be a pretty basic question but is there a way I can make the functions see the modules already imported in my notebook ?
One way obviously is to import the needed modules in the .py file but wanted to know if there are any other cleaner ways.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import all the necessary functions in the script, not in jupyter notebook.

When you call functions/classes from the script, they "see" only libraries imported in the script. This is actually the cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will keep importing in the script then.